# plot a circle with pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

surprisingly I didn't find a straight-forward description on how to draw a circle with matplotlib.pyplot (please no pylab) taking as input center (x,y) and radius r. I tried some variants of this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
circle=plt.Circle((0,0),2)
# here must be something like circle.plot() or not?
plt.show()
```

... but still didn't get it working.

Comment: I'm sure it's possible to do this, but matplotlib is aimed mainly at plotting (i.e. here are some data, put them on a graph), not drawing, so it might not be entirely straightforward.

Comment: Radius of scatterplot points is increasingly used to visualize data. Google charts calls them "bubble plots". Gapminder.org is a good exmaple. This *is* plotting, not drawing. I searched the matplotlib github repo for "bubble" and "scatter radius" to no avail, so I don't think this is on the to-do list as far as adding a feature.

Comment: plt.scatter() does take a size argument. You can pass lists for the x- and y-coordinates of circles, the circles' radii, and the circles' colors. http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.scatter . My error earlier, in thinking that such functionality was not already in matplotlib.

Comment: Just to mention: `plt.Circle(..)` directs to `matplotlib.patches.Circle()`. So a solution without pyplot would be `circle = matplotlib.patches.Circle(..); axes.add_artist(circle)`.

Answer (score 333, accepted):

You need to add it to an axes. A [`Circle`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Circle.html) is a subclass of an [`Patch`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Patch.html), and an `axes` has an [`add_patch`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.add_patch.html) method. (You can also use [`add_artist`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.add_artist.html) but it's not recommended.)

Here's an example of doing this:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

circle1 = plt.Circle((0, 0), 0.2, color='r')
circle2 = plt.Circle((0.5, 0.5), 0.2, color='blue')
circle3 = plt.Circle((1, 1), 0.2, color='g', clip_on=False)

fig, ax = plt.subplots() # note we must use plt.subplots, not plt.subplot
# (or if you have an existing figure)
# fig = plt.gcf()
# ax = fig.gca()

ax.add_patch(circle1)
ax.add_patch(circle2)
ax.add_patch(circle3)

fig.savefig('plotcircles.png')
```

This results in the following figure:

[image]

The first circle is at the origin, but by default `clip_on` is `True`, so the circle is clipped when ever it extends beyond the `axes`. The third (green) circle shows what happens when you don't clip the `Artist`. It extends beyond the axes (but not beyond the figure, ie the figure size is *not* automatically adjusted to plot all of your artists).

The units for x, y and radius correspond to data units by default. In this case, I didn't plot anything on my axes (`fig.gca()` returns the current axes), and since the limits have never been set, they defaults to an x and y range from 0 to 1.

Here's a continuation of the example, showing how units matter:

```py
circle1 = plt.Circle((0, 0), 2, color='r')
# now make a circle with no fill, which is good for hi-lighting key results
circle2 = plt.Circle((5, 5), 0.5, color='b', fill=False)
circle3 = plt.Circle((10, 10), 2, color='g', clip_on=False)
    
ax = plt.gca()
ax.cla() # clear things for fresh plot

# change default range so that new circles will work
ax.set_xlim((0, 10))
ax.set_ylim((0, 10))
# some data
ax.plot(range(11), 'o', color='black')
# key data point that we are encircling
ax.plot((5), (5), 'o', color='y')
    
ax.add_patch(circle1)
ax.add_patch(circle2)
ax.add_patch(circle3)
fig.savefig('plotcircles2.png')
```

which results in:

[image]

You can see how I set the fill of the 2nd circle to `False`, which is useful for encircling key results (like my yellow data point).

Comment: I like this answer because you're "drawing" a circle, rather than plotting. Though plotting would have been my first instinct too.

Comment: Why do artists like Ellipse not respect pylab.ion() or matplotlib.interactive(True)? E.g., a call to xlabel() (after calling ion() or interactive(True)) updates the figure immediately, but anything involving these Ellipse objects requires an explicit pylab.show() or matplotlib.show().

Comment: FYI: It looks like the Circle class has moved from matplotlib.pyplot to matplotlib.patches since this answer was written.

Comment: But but but the circles are oval!

Comment: @rubenvb see my other answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9230389/why-is-matplotlib-plotting-my-circles-as-ovals/9232513#9232513

Comment: why the circles are all flattened?

Comment: @pavon For me `matplotlib.pyplot.Circle == matplotlib.patches.Circle` evaluates to `True`, so they are probably aliases.

Comment: For round circles, the simplest way is to write: ax.set_aspect('equal')

Comment: @Yann I tried to put the plot function in a loop and call `ax.add_artist(Circle(i,j,0.4,color='blue'))` where `i,j` get their values from 2 nested loops for a total of 16 circles. Unfortunately, `plt.show()` and `fig.savefig('plotcircles2.png')` are showing only very small part of the plot (first 2 circles). Is it possible to show the entire figure with all the patch circles in it.

Comment: This is old advice and is misleading: you need to use `add_patch()` since `Circle` is a subclass of `Patch`. Not `add_artist()` ; its doc even tells you *"Only use `add_artist` for artists for which there is no dedicated "add_xyz" method"*

Comment: how to create a legend for these circles?

Comment: @smci It's a shame that `ax.add_artist(obj)` does not try to get the dedicated method of that object directly, if it exists. Then we could always add artists that way without knowing the implementation details.

Answer (score 114):

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

circle1 = plt.Circle((0, 0), 0.2, color='r')
plt.gca().add_patch(circle1)
```

A quick condensed version of the accepted answer, to quickly plug a circle into an existing plot. Refer to the accepted answer and other answers to understand the details.

By the way:

- `gca()` means Get Current Axis

Comment: Perfect! just exactly what I needed to see right now.Your 'By the way' was quite helpful too! `dir(fig)` shows me over 30 'get' methods, but `gca` has no `get_current_axis` alias. These kinds of fyi answers are wonderful.

Comment: you can actually do `plt.gca()` instead of `plt.gcf().gca()`

Answer (score 43):

If you want to plot a set of circles, you might want to see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24567352/2144720) or [this gist](https://gist.github.com/syrte/592a062c562cd2a98a83)(a bit newer). The post offered a function named `circles`.

The function `circles` works like `scatter`, but the sizes of plotted circles are in data unit.

Here's an example:

```
from pylab import *
figure(figsize=(8,8))
ax=subplot(aspect='equal')

#plot one circle (the biggest one on bottom-right)
circles(1, 0, 0.5, 'r', alpha=0.2, lw=5, edgecolor='b', transform=ax.transAxes)

#plot a set of circles (circles in diagonal)
a=arange(11)
out = circles(a, a, a*0.2, c=a, alpha=0.5, edgecolor='none')
colorbar(out)

xlim(0,10)
ylim(0,10)
```

[image]

Comment: What does `transform=ax.transAxes` do?

Comment: @Lee That's for the circle in right-lower corner, transform the data into axes coordinate, i.e. (1,1) means right-upper corner in axes, (1,0) means right-lower corner, etc.

Comment: This should be a part of matplotlib.

Comment: Can this be used with `mplleaflet` ? If so, could you provide an example, please ?

Comment: @fmalaussena As this code snippet is pure `matplotlib`, I guess it should be compatible with `mplleaflet` though I never tried.

Answer (score 22):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def xy(r,phi):
  return r*np.cos(phi), r*np.sin(phi)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111,aspect='equal')  

phis=np.arange(0,6.28,0.01)
r =1.
ax.plot( *xy(r,phis), c='r',ls='-' )
plt.show()
```

Or, if you prefer, look at the `path`s, http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/path_tutorial.html

Comment: Trignometric equation of a circle and  degress  0 tp 360 , which translates to 0 to  6.28319 radians http://www.mathopenref.com/coordparamcircle.html

Comment: Would you mind letting me know that why you add * in front of the function name, I.e., *xy(r,phis).    Thanks

Comment: @sleevechen the * unpacks the returned 2-tuple from the function into to separate arguments. See https://runestone.academy/runestone/books/published/fopp/Tuples/UnpackingArgumentsToFunctions.html

Answer (score 21):

If you aim to have the "circle" maintain a visual aspect ratio of 1 no matter what the data coordinates are, you could use the scatter() method. http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.scatter

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
r = [100, 80, 60, 40, 20] # in points, not data units
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.scatter(x, y, s=r)
fig.show()
```

[image: Image is a scatter plot. Five circles along the line y=10x have decreasing radii from bottom left to top right. Although the graph is square-shaped, the y-axis has 10 times the range of the x-axis. Even so, the aspect ratio of the circles is 1 on the screen.]

Comment: Excellent input!

Answer (score 15):

Extending the accepted answer for a common usecase. In particular:

1. View the circles at a natural aspect ratio.
2. Automatically extend the axes limits to include the newly plotted circles.

Self-contained example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.add_patch(plt.Circle((0, 0), 0.2, color='r', alpha=0.5))
ax.add_patch(plt.Circle((1, 1), 0.5, color='#00ffff', alpha=0.5))
ax.add_artist(plt.Circle((1, 0), 0.5, color='#000033', alpha=0.5))

#Use adjustable='box-forced' to make the plot area square-shaped as well.
ax.set_aspect('equal', adjustable='datalim')
ax.plot()   #Causes an autoscale update.
plt.show()
```

Note the difference between **`ax.add_patch(..)`** and **`ax.add_artist(..)`**: of the two, only the former makes autoscaling machinery take the circle into account (reference: [discussion](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/2202/)), so after running the above code we get:

[image: add_patch(..) vs add_artist(..)]

See also: [`set_aspect(..)` documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_aspect.html).

Comment: In python3, you need to take out `fig, ax = plt.subplots()`, otherwise you'll get two windows (one is blank).

Answer (score 15):

I see plots with the use of (.circle) but based on what you might want to do you can also try this out:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = list(range(1,6))
y = list(range(10, 20, 2))

print(x, y)

for i, data in enumerate(zip(x,y)):
    j, k = data
    plt.scatter(j,k, marker = "o", s = ((i+1)**4)*50, alpha = 0.3)
```

[image: Simple concentric circle plot using linear progressing points]

```
centers = np.array([[5,18], [3,14], [7,6]])
m, n = make_blobs(n_samples=20, centers=[[5,18], [3,14], [7,6]], n_features=2, 
cluster_std = 0.4)
colors = ['g', 'b', 'r', 'm']

plt.figure(num=None, figsize=(7,6), facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')
plt.scatter(m[:,0], m[:,1])

for i in range(len(centers)):

    plt.scatter(centers[i,0], centers[i,1], color = colors[i], marker = 'o', s = 13000, alpha = 0.2)
    plt.scatter(centers[i,0], centers[i,1], color = 'k', marker = 'x', s = 50)

plt.savefig('plot.png')
```

[image: Circled points of a classification problem.]

Comment: What is `make_blobs`?

Comment: scikit-learn has a `make_blobs` function: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.make_blobs.html

Answer (score 0):

Hello I have written a code for drawing a circle.
It will help for drawing all kind of circles.
[The image shows the circle with radius 1 and center at 0,0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPxfA.png)
The center and radius can be edited of any choice.

```
## Draw a circle with center and radius defined
## Also enable the coordinate axes
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
# Define limits of coordinate system
x1 = -1.5
x2 = 1.5
y1 = -1.5
y2 = 1.5

circle1 = plt.Circle((0,0),1, color = 'k', fill = False, clip_on = False)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.add_artist(circle1)
plt.axis("equal")
ax.spines['left'].set_position('zero')
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('zero')
ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')
plt.xlim(left=x1)
plt.xlim(right=x2)
plt.ylim(bottom=y1)
plt.ylim(top=y2)
plt.axhline(linewidth=2, color='k')
plt.axvline(linewidth=2, color='k')

##plt.grid(True)
plt.grid(color='k', linestyle='-.', linewidth=0.5)
plt.show()
```

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Similarly to scatter plot you can also use normal plot with circle line style. Using `markersize` parameter you can adjust radius of a circle:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(200, 2, 'o', markersize=7)
```