# Align matplotlib scatter marker left and or right

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I am using the `matplotlib` scatterplot function to create the appearance of handles on vertical lines to delineate certain parts of a graph.  However, in order to make them look correct, I need to be able to align the scatter plot marker to the left (for the left line / delineator) and / or right (for the right line / delineator).

Here's an example:

```
#create the figure
fig = plt.figure(facecolor = '#f3f3f3', figsize = (11.5, 6))
ax = plt. ax = plt.subplot2grid((1, 1), (0,0))

#make some random data
index = pandas.DatetimeIndex(start = '01/01/2000', freq  = 'b', periods = 100)
rand_levels = pandas.DataFrame( numpy.random.randn(100, 4)/252., index = index, columns = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
rand_levels = 100*numpy.exp(rand_levels.cumsum(axis = 0))
ax.stackplot(rand_levels.index, rand_levels.transpose())

#create the place holder for the vertical lines
d1, d2 = index[25], index[50]

#draw the lines
ymin, ymax = ax.get_ylim()
ax.vlines([index[25], index[50]], ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax, color = '#353535', lw = 2)

#draw the markers
ax.scatter(d1, ymax, clip_on = False, color = '#353535', marker = '>', s = 200, zorder = 3)
ax.scatter(d2, ymax, clip_on = False, color = '#353535', marker = '<', s = 200, zorder = 3)

#reset the limits
ax.set_ylim(ymin, ymax)
ax.set_xlim(rand_levels.index[0], rand_levels.index[-1])
plt.show()
```

The code above gives me **almost** the graph I'm looking for, like this:

[image: focus_timeline]

However, I'd like the leftmost marker (">") to be "aligned left" (i.e. shifted slightly to the right) so that the line is continued to the back of the marker Likewise, I'd like the rightmost marker ("<") to be "aligned right" (i.e. slightly shifted to the left).  Like this:

[image: desired_fig]

Any guidance or suggestions on how to accomplish this in a flexible manner?

**NOTE:** In practice, my `DataFrame` index is `pandas.Datetime` not integers as I've provided for this simple example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I liked this question and was not satisfied with my first answer.  In particular, it seemed unnecessarily cumbersome to create figure specific objects (`mark_align_*`) in order to align markers. What I eventually found was the functionality to specify a marker by *verts* (a list of 2-element floats, or an Nx2 array, that specifies the marker vertices relative to the target plot-point at `(0, 0)`). To utilize this functionality for this purpose I wrote this function,

```
from matplotlib import markers
from matplotlib.path import Path

def align_marker(marker, halign='center', valign='middle',):
    """
    create markers with specified alignment.

    Parameters
    ----------

    marker : a valid marker specification.
      See mpl.markers

    halign : string, float {'left', 'center', 'right'}
      Specifies the horizontal alignment of the marker. *float* values
      specify the alignment in units of the markersize/2 (0 is 'center',
      -1 is 'right', 1 is 'left').

    valign : string, float {'top', 'middle', 'bottom'}
      Specifies the vertical alignment of the marker. *float* values
      specify the alignment in units of the markersize/2 (0 is 'middle',
      -1 is 'top', 1 is 'bottom').

    Returns
    -------

    marker_array : numpy.ndarray
      A Nx2 array that specifies the marker path relative to the
      plot target point at (0, 0).

    Notes
    -----
    The mark_array can be passed directly to ax.plot and ax.scatter, e.g.::

        ax.plot(1, 1, marker=align_marker('>', 'left'))

    """

    if isinstance(halign, (str, unicode)):
        halign = {'right': -1.,
                  'middle': 0.,
                  'center': 0.,
                  'left': 1.,
                  }[halign]

    if isinstance(valign, (str, unicode)):
        valign = {'top': -1.,
                  'middle': 0.,
                  'center': 0.,
                  'bottom': 1.,
                  }[valign]

    # Define the base marker
    bm = markers.MarkerStyle(marker)

    # Get the marker path and apply the marker transform to get the
    # actual marker vertices (they should all be in a unit-square
    # centered at (0, 0))
    m_arr = bm.get_path().transformed(bm.get_transform()).vertices

    # Shift the marker vertices for the specified alignment.
    m_arr[:, 0] += halign / 2
    m_arr[:, 1] += valign / 2

    return Path(m_arr, bm.get_path().codes)
```

Using this function, the desired markers can be plotted as,

```
ax.plot(d1, 1, marker=align_marker('>', halign='left'), ms=20,
        clip_on=False, color='k', transform=ax.get_xaxis_transform())
ax.plot(d2, 1, marker=align_marker('<', halign='right'), ms=20,
        clip_on=False, color='k', transform=ax.get_xaxis_transform())
```

or using `ax.scatter`,

```
ax.scatter(d1, 1, 200, marker=align_marker('>', halign='left'),
           clip_on=False, color='k', transform=ax.get_xaxis_transform())
ax.scatter(d2, 1, 200, marker=align_marker('<', halign='right'),
           clip_on=False, color='k', transform=ax.get_xaxis_transform())
```

In both of these examples I have specified `transform=ax.get_xaxis_transform()` so that the vertical position of the markers is in axes coordinates (`1` is the top of the axes), this has nothing to do with the marker *alignment*.

The obvious advantage of this solution compared to my previous one is that it does not require knowledge of the *markersize*, *plotting function* (`ax.plot` vs. `ax.scatter`), or *axes* (for the transform).  Instead, one simply specifes a marker and its alignment!

Cheers!

Comment: In the course of searching for an alternate solution I tried to supply a customized `matplotlib.markers.MarkerStyle` instance to the `marker` input option of `ax.plot` and `ax.scatter`, but this functionality does not yet appear to be supported.

Comment: Wow @farenorth... just wow. First of all, it looks like by using the `markers.MarkerStyle` class, you were able to solve the issue without having to pass the `figure` to the function (which is big plus for me).  I need to implement what you've done to make sure I'm using / understanding it correctly, but this is a really elegant abstraction / solution!

Comment: Just put together some tester functions and this works beautifully without needing to pass the figure (and much clearer & more expressive language).  Terrific solution!

Comment: Thank you very much for putting so much effort in this anser! This should actually included in matplotlib as parameters for markers.

Comment: Why this does not work: ax.plot(d1, 1, marker=align_marker('_', halign='left'), ms=20,
        clip_on=False, color='k', transform=ax.get_xaxis_transform())

Comment: @Oren, good Q. This appears to be a bug in the way markers are created. I've created an [issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/7807), and [proposed a solution](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/7809). For now, I've updated my function with a workaround.

Comment: One other note: at least for me, using this changes the interpretation of the `s` keyword argument to `ax.scatter`. I'm not entirely sure I understand why, but I think it might have to do with the transform applied.

Answer (score 8):

I found a simple solution to this problem. Matplotlib have built-in markers with different alignments:
[lines_bars_and_markers example code: marker_reference.py](https://matplotlib.org/examples/lines_bars_and_markers/marker_reference.html)
[image]

Simply change the `'>'` marker to `9` and the `'<'` marker to `8`:

```
#draw the markers
ax.scatter(d1, ymax, clip_on=False, color='#353535', marker=9, s=200, zorder=3)
ax.scatter(d2, ymax, clip_on=False, color='#353535', marker=8, s=200, zorder=3)
```

Answer (score 2):

One solution would be to use [mpl.transforms](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/advanced/transforms_tutorial.html), and the `transform` input parameter to `ax.scatter` or `ax.plot`.  Specifically, I would start by adding,

```
from matplotlib import transforms as tf
```

In this approach I use `tf.offset_copy` to create markers that are offset by half of their size. But what are the size of markers? It turns out that `ax.scatter` and `ax.plot` specify marker sizes differently. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14827650/pyplot-scatter-plot-marker-size) for more info.

1. The `s=` input parameter to `ax.scatter` specifies marker sizes in points^2 (i.e. this is the area of the square that the markers fit into).
2. The `markersize` input parameter to `ax.plot` specifies the width and height of the markers in points (i.e. the width and height of the square that the markers fit into).

### Using `ax.scatter`

So, if you want to plot your markers with `ax.scatter` you could do,

```
ms_scatter = 200  # define markersize
mark_align_left_scatter = tf.offset_copy(ax.get_xaxis_transform(), fig,
                                         ms_scatter ** 0.5 / 2,
                                         units='points')
mark_align_right_scatter = tf.offset_copy(ax.get_xaxis_transform(), fig,
                                          -ms_scatter ** 0.5 / 2,
                                          units='points')
```

Here I have used the `ax.get_xaxis_transform`, which is a transform that places points in data-coordinates along the x-axis, but in *axes* (0 to 1) coordinates on the y-axis. This way, rather than using `ymax`, I can place the point at the top of the plot with `1`. Furthermore, if I pan or zoom the figure, the markers will still be at the top!  Once I've defined the new transforms, I assign them to the `transform` property when I call `ax.scatter`,

```
ax.scatter(d1, 1, s=ms_scatter, marker='>', transform=mark_align_left_scatter,
           clip_on=False, color='k')
ax.scatter(d2, 1, s=ms_scatter, marker='<', transform=mark_align_right_scatter,
           clip_on=False, color='k')
```

### Using `ax.plot`

Because it is somewhat simpler, I would probably use `ax.plot`. In that case I would do,

```
ms = 20

mark_align_left = tf.offset_copy(ax.get_xaxis_transform(), fig,
                                 ms / 2, units='points')
mark_align_right = tf.offset_copy(ax.get_xaxis_transform(), fig,
                                  -ms / 2, units='points')

ax.plot(d1, 1, marker='>', ms=ms, transform=mark_align_left,
        clip_on=False, color='k')
ax.plot(d2, 1, marker='<', ms=ms, transform=mark_align_right,
        clip_on=False, color='k')
```

### Final Comments

You may want to create a wrapper to make creation of the `mark_align_*` transforms easier, but I'll leave that for you to implement if you want to.

Whether you use `ax.scatter` or `ax.plot` your output plot will look something like,

[image: Final figure]

Comment: You may also want to look at `ax.axvline` in place of `ax.vlines`. `ax.axvline` doesn't need the ymin and ymax values.

Comment: That was nothing short of a spectacularly thorough answer, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Not the most elegant solution, but if I'm understanding your question correctly, subtracting and adding one from/to `d1` and `d2` respectively should do it:

```
ax.scatter(d1-1, ymax, clip_on = False, color = '#353535', marker = '>', s = 200, zorder = 3)
ax.scatter(d2+1, ymax, clip_on = False, color = '#353535', marker = '<', s = 200, zorder = 3)
```

Comment: take a peek at my NOTE, I state that in my actual problem the `DataFrame` index is dates, and this needs to be a flexible solution, not one that just works for the example. Thanks so much for your thoughts, though.

Comment: Oh, I missed that part. Could you provide sample code in which the `DataFrame` is `pandas.Datetime` then?

Comment: Just added the code to made the `Index` of type `Datetime` instead of `int`

Comment: Looks like if you change `freq  = 'b'` to `freq  = 'h'` or `freq  = 'd'` the posted solution works

Comment: this is just sample data that I've generated. It will have real dates (that are most-like 'business days'), so unfortunately, I can't just change `'b'` to `'h'`.