# Matplotlib: plotting marker on edge of line

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I want to plot some data, but instead of having the marker centered on the line, I need to have the lower vertex of the triangle aligned with the line. How can this be done?

Here is my MWE:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as mplt

data = [1.]*10

mplt.plot(data, 'rv-' )
mplt.show()
```

Cheers,
Jorge

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to achieve this is to use a special set of markers [defined](http://matplotlib.org/api/markers_api.html) in `matplotlib`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as mplt
from matplotlib.markers import CARETDOWN

data = [1.]*10

mplt.plot(data, 'r-')
mplt.scatter(range(10), data, marker=CARETDOWN, facecolor='r')
mplt.show()
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't render into a triangle as clear as the one in the OP for me. If you're aiming for more visulal clarity, perhaps writing something along the lines of answers to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26686722/) would be a better option.

Comment: Hi Vlas, thank you for your answer, looks cleaner than my solution. I managed to do what I wanted using polygons, but it is much more cumbersome.