# Adjusting dot size in scatterplot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, scatter-plot

I am doing

```
ax = df.plot(x=x_col, y=y_col, style=['o', 'rx'])
```

but I don't like that the data points are large circles. I have thousands of datapoints, so it makes the plot ugly. Any idea how I can make the dots smaller, i.e. have them be actual points, rather than circles? Or any alternative suggestions for this sort of scatterplot?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `DataFrame.plot()` [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) include the option to pass keyword arguments to the underlying `matplotlib` plotting method. As you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14827650/pyplot-scatter-plot-marker-size), there's an argument `s` for the dot size. So you should be able to:

```
ax = df.plot(kind='scatter', x=x_col, y=y_col, style=['o', 'rx'], s=12)
```

This is also illustrated in the `pandas` [visualization docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html#scatter-plot).

Answer (score 1):

The [valid matplotlib marker styles](http://matplotlib.org/api/markers_api.html#module-matplotlib.markers) include;  `'.'` (point) and `','` (pixel).

So an alternative could be:

```
ax = df.plot(x=x_col, y=y_col, style=['.', 'rx'])
```