# Change marker size in Seaborn Factorplot

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

I'm trying to change the markersize in Seaborn factorplots but I am not sure what keyword argument to pass

```
import seaborn as sns
exercise = sns.load_dataset("exercise")
g = sns.factorplot(x="time", y="pulse", hue="kind", data=exercise, ci= .95)
```

I tried passing **markersize** and **s** based off of these StackOverFlow answers but neither seem to have an effect

[image: Seaborn_Example]

[pyplot scatter plot marker size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14827650/pyplot-scatter-plot-marker-size)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`Factorplot` is calling the underlying function `pointplot` on default which accepts the argument `markers`. This is used to differentiate the markershapes. The size for all lines and markers can be changed with the `scale` argument.

```
exercise = sns.load_dataset("exercise")
g = sns.factorplot(x="time", y="pulse", hue="kind", data=exercise, ci=95, 
               markers=['o', 'v', 's'], 
               scale = 1.5)
```

[Same data as above with different shapes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqaFZ.png)

Please also note the `ci` argument in your example, .95 would result in a different figure with ci's hardly to see.

Comment: If you are using `kind='swarm'` in the factorplot, `scale` throws an error but using the keyword argument `s` does work in this case