# change scatter plot marker thickness

Tags: python, matplotlib

How can you change the thickness of marker lines in a scatter plot `plt.scatter()`? `markeredgewidth` is a valid attribute in `plt.plot()`; is there any equivalent attribute for `scatter` plots?

For example, when you change the size of a scatter plot (with `marker = 'x'`), the markers only get bigger, but the line thickness doesn't change.

I'm not trying to change the size but line thickness!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pyplot scatter plot marker size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14827650/pyplot-scatter-plot-marker-size)

Comment: No i'm not trying to change the size, but I need the thickness - please read the post

Comment: Please explain thickness vs. size

Comment: When you change the size of `marker = 'x'`, it only gets bigger, but I want this to be thicker as well. `markeredgewidth` does the same for `plt.plot()`

Comment: "line thickness" and "thickness" are not the same thing.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

you are looking for the kwarg `linewidths`. e.g.:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x = y = np.arange(5)

fig,ax = plt.subplots(1)

ax.scatter(x,y,  s=100,marker='x',color='b',linewidths=1)
ax.scatter(x,y+1,s=100,marker='x',color='r',linewidths=2)
ax.scatter(x,y+2,s=100,marker='x',color='g',linewidths=3)

plt.show()
```

Note: On some versions of `matplotlib`, it appears the kwarg is `linewidth`, not `linewidths`, despite what the [manual currently says](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html) (April 2020). This is a [known issue on the matplotlib github](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/17192).

[image]

Comment: Maybe something changed, but for me it was `linewidth`, not `linewidths`.  No 's'.

Comment: In the installed docs for version 2.2.2 (currently latest stable version I think) in Python 3 it's saying `linewidths`.

Answer (score 2):

In **Ubuntu-18.04** and installed **matplotlib==3.2.0** with **python-3.6.9**, you just need to set `linewidth` attribute (Not `linewidths`):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x = y = np.arange(5)

fig,ax = plt.subplots(1)

ax.scatter(x,y,  s=100,marker='x',color='b',linewidth=1)
ax.scatter(x,y+1,s=100,marker='x',color='r',linewidth=2)
ax.scatter(x,y+2,s=100,marker='x',color='g',linewidth=6)

plt.show()
```

[image]