# Scatter plot a DataFrame grouped by 2 columns and having an aggregation

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to do a scatter plot over the number of items in the DataFrame for each date/time combination. I've grouped data like this:

```
dff = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(['date', 'time']).size().rename('count'))
```

and it looks like this:

```
                           count
date         time       
2017-05-19   15:00         1
             15:30         1
             16:00         1
             16:30         1
             17:00         1
2017-05-23   10:00         2
             10:30         2
             11:00         2
...
```

Now, how can I scatter plot the counts having `date`s on the X axis and `time`s on the Y axis? `plt.scatter(x, y, s=area, c=colors)` is the signature, but however I try to select `x` and `y` from `dff`, it fails to find the keys. Also, `scatter` expects floats on the axes, while I have strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This requires accessing the `MultiIndex` values like so:

```
# replicating sample data (foo is just dummy data for the count)
grouped = df.groupby(['date', 'time'])['foo'].count()
date        time    
2015-01-01  15:00:00    1
            15:30:00    1
2015-01-02  16:00:00    2
Name: foo, dtype: int64

plt.scatter(x=grouped.index.get_level_values(0), y=grouped.index.get_level_values(1), s=[20*4**n for n in grouped.values])
plt.show()
```

You'll need to play with the `s` argument in `scatter()`, here's the doc I was using for this- [pyplot scatter plot marker size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14827650/pyplot-scatter-plot-marker-size).

[image]