# why my scatter plot in python giving all red when using "s" parameter

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

when i am using s parameter for bubble whole plot is red
 [When using "s" parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1mEe.jpg)

```
# Import numpy as np
import numpy as np

# Store pop as a numpy array: np_pop
np_pop = np.array(pop)

# Double np_pop
np_pop = np_pop*2

# Update: set s argument to np_pop
plt.scatter(gdp_cap, life_exp ,alpha = 0.8,color ='red', s = np_pop)

# Previous customizations
plt.xscale('log') 
plt.xlabel('GDP per Capita [in USD]')
plt.ylabel('Life Expectancy [in years]')
plt.title('World Development in 2007')
plt.xticks([1000, 10000, 100000],['1k', '10k', '100k'])

# Display the plot
plt.show()
```

when s parameter is not used it shows constant bubble size but i want bubble size to be dependent on population
[when s parameter is not used it doesn't show red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yOAL.jpg)

```
# Import numpy as np
import numpy as np

# Store pop as a numpy array: np_pop
np_pop = np.array(pop)

# Double np_pop
np_pop = np_pop*2

# Update: set s argument to np_pop
plt.scatter(gdp_cap, life_exp ,alpha = 0.8,color ='red')

# Previous customizations
plt.xscale('log') 
plt.xlabel('GDP per Capita [in USD]')
plt.ylabel('Life Expectancy [in years]')
plt.title('World Development in 2007')
plt.xticks([1000, 10000, 100000],['1k', '10k', '100k'])

# Display the plot
plt.show()
```

Comment: Have you tried with a very small `np_pop`? i guess the bubbles are so big that cover all plot

Comment: Also, creating a [mcve] will be very helpful for us to help figure out the problem

Comment: have to check this thanks Joe

Comment: Try the solution on this page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14827650/pyplot-scatter-plot-marker-size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with a smaller `np_pop`:

```
np_pop = np_pop/5000 # or any other value that decrease the population(?)
```

Comment: @AkashSoni you are welcome, please consider to accept the answer by clicking on the tick on the left side of the answer :) https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work