# How to create a graph varying point size?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following dataframe:

```
               Madrugada  Mañana  Tarde  Noche
Lunes              1       2      3      4
Martes             5       6      7      8
Miércoles          9      10     11     12
Jueves            13      14     15     16
Viernes           17      18     19     20
Sábado            21      22     23     24
Domingo           25      26     27     28
```

Created with:

```
 import pandas as pd
index = ['Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miércoles', 'Jueves', 'Viernes', 'Sábado', 'Domingo']
columns = ['Madrugada','Mañana', 'Tarde', 'Noche']
Cuadro = pd.DataFrame(index=index, columns=columns)

Cuadro.loc['Lunes'] = pd.Series({'Madrugada':1, 'Mañana':2, 'Tarde':3,
          'Noche':4})
Cuadro.loc['Martes'] = pd.Series({'Madrugada':5, 'Mañana':6, 'Tarde':7,
          'Noche':8})
Cuadro.loc['Miércoles'] = pd.Series({'Madrugada':9, 'Mañana':10, 'Tarde':11,
          'Noche':12})
Cuadro.loc['Jueves'] = pd.Series({'Madrugada':13, 'Mañana':14, 'Tarde':15,
          'Noche':16})
Cuadro.loc['Viernes'] = pd.Series({'Madrugada':17, 'Mañana':18, 'Tarde':19,
          'Noche':20})
Cuadro.loc['Sábado'] = pd.Series({'Madrugada':21, 'Mañana':22, 'Tarde':23,
          'Noche':24})
Cuadro.loc['Domingo'] = pd.Series({'Madrugada':25, 'Mañana':26, 'Tarde':27,
          'Noche':28})
print(Cuadro)
```

How may I create a graph like:

```
                      Data Usage:

|Midnight          o
|
|Night                                                             OOO
|                                                                      OOO
|Afternoon
|
|            o          O     O          (   )      
|Morning__________________________________________________________________

              M      T       W           Th         F          Sat          Sun
```

Where the size of the points is dependant on the value of the cell?
Thanking you in advance for any help or recommendation...
Jose

Comment: You can add a list of sizes to matplotlib's `scatter`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14827650/pyplot-scatter-plot-marker-size

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, How that could be implemented to create a graph with varying point size (dependant on the value of the cell) as described above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> data.csv

```
Day,Midnight,Morning,Afternoon,Night
Monday,4.002900,30.905096,25.193066,23.704473
Tuesday,22.074967,16.407200,50.409445,27.396373
Wednesday,18.875000,28.415111,22.205521,25.744592
Thursday,12.470333,16.265086,15.390797,81.988800
Friday,NaN,33.658050,23.814764,20.096790
Saturday,12.647037,16.545295,25.620673,14.903473
Sunday,4.975500,19.023320,21.215298,45.440120
```

> code.py

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(df['Day'], ['Midnight']*7, s=20*df['Midnight'])
ax.scatter(df['Day'], ['Morning']*7, s=20*df['Morning'])
ax.scatter(df['Day'], ['Afternoon']*7, s=20*df['Afternoon'])
ax.scatter(df['Day'], ['Night']*7, s=20*df['Night'])
plt.ylabel('Time of Day')
plt.xlabel('Day of the Week')
plt.show()
```

> Resulting Plot

[image]

Comment: It was exactly what I was needing to finish my project 

Comment: If it helped you can designate an accepted answer with the check mark to the left of my answer. Cheers :)

Comment: How did you learn to graph like that? Would you please, be so kind as to give me some advice on where to get Matplotlib graphing tips? Thanking you in advance...Jose

Comment: Practice and reading the documentation; honestly I haven't found any great resources but maybe I should create one.

Comment: Looking forward to read it whenever published, please let us know to be able to get better at Ploting with Matplolib...Thanks!