# Matplotlib - Move text label right by 'x' points

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following code which produces a bubble chart, and then adds the labels as text to the plot:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (5,10))

# create data
x = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
y = ['A','B','C','D',
     'E','F','G','H','I','']
z = [10,20,80,210,390,1050,2180,4690,13040,0]

labels = [1,2,8,21,39,105,218,469,1304]

plt.xlim(0.9,1.1)

for i, txt in enumerate(labels):
    ax.annotate(txt, (x[i], y[i]), ha='center', va='center', )

plt.scatter(x, y, s=z*4000, c="#8C4799", alpha=0.3)
```

[image]

I have the text labels centered vertically and horizontally (i.e. the 1304,469 etc), but ideally I want it shifted to the right so it is away from the bubble. I have tried `ha=right`, but it only nudges it a tiny bit.

Is there anything I can use to move it completely away from the bubble? I.e. code I can put it the following `for loop`:

```
for i, txt in enumerate(labels):
    ax.annotate(txt, (x[i], y[i]), ha='center', va='center', )
```

Comment: `ax.annotate(txt, (x[i]+1, y[i]), ha='center', va='center')` ?

Comment: Hey, thank you. It doesn't work for me unfortunately

Comment: I can see why it didn't work, it was going off my plot. I have thumbed your response up as it may help someone :)... thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the size `s` of the bubbles is `s=z*4000`, a bubble's radius is `np.sqrt(z*4000)/2`. (For an explanation see [scatter plot marker size](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47403507/4124317)).

You would hence create an annotation which is positionned at the center of the bubbles in data coordinates and offset it by `np.sqrt(z*4000)/2` in units of points (or possibly 2 or 3 points more to have it look nicely).

This would be done using

```
annotate("text", xy=(x[i],y[i]), 
         xytext=(np.sqrt(z[i]*4000)/2+2, 0),  textcoords="offset points")
```

Complete example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (5,10))

# create data
x = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
y = ['A','B','C','D',
     'E','F','G','H','I','']
z = [10,20,80,210,390,1050,2180,4690,13040,0]

labels = [1,2,8,21,39,105,218,469,1304]

plt.xlim(0.9,1.1)


sc = plt.scatter(x, y, s=z*4000, c="#8C4799", alpha=0.3)

for txt, size, xi, yi in zip(labels, sc.get_sizes(), x,y):
    ax.annotate(txt, xy=(xi,yi), xytext=(np.sqrt(size)/2+2, 0),
                textcoords="offset points",
                ha='left', va='center', )

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

the parameter `xytext` of `ax.annotate` lets you do this:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (5,10))

# create data
x = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
y = ['A','B','C','D',
     'E','F','G','H','I','']
z = [10,20,80,210,390,1050,2180,4690,13040,0]

labels = [1,2,8,21,39,105,218,469,1304]

plt.xlim(0.9,1.1)

for i, txt in enumerate(labels):
    ax.annotate(txt, (x[i], y[i]), ha='center', va='center', xytext=(1.05,y[i]) )

plt.scatter(x, y, s=z*4000, c="#8C4799", alpha=0.3)
```

Brings this:

[image]

Edit: if you want the labels to be just to the right of every circle, you'll have to create an array of positions and then loop through it

Comment: Hey, thank you for your help. I have tried your code, and it was the same as my code. Do you have the code you used for your chart? :)

Comment: Sorry, I don't know why it disappeared. Now it's complete !

Answer (score 2):

I would simply use an offset percentage (20% for example) to reposition the x-coordinate of the text. Additionally you can turn off the manual setting of x-limits.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(4, 10))

x = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
y = ['A','B','C','D',
     'E','F','G','H','I','']
z = [10,20,80,210,390,1050,2180,4690,13040,0]

labels = [1,2,8,21,39,105,218,469,1304]

for i, txt in enumerate(labels):
    ax.annotate(txt, (x[i]*1.2, y[i]), ha='center', va='center', )

plt.scatter(x, y, s=z*4000, c="#8C4799", alpha=0.3)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Works perfectly. That is a really nifty way of doing it, thank you!