# About what scatter plot is proportional?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib-basemap, scatter

i'm using a scatter plot with Basemap (under python3.7) for my job but i can't find somewhere in which maneer the circles are proportional to my values. Is the values are proportional to the area of the circle ? proportional to the radius? i's not really the same, there a ^2 factor between the 2 ! 
Thanks a lot !!

Clem

Comment: In the related document: https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html, it reads `The marker size in points**2. Default is rcParams['lines.markersize'] ** 2.`.

Comment: Thank you a lot ! i didn't find the information the first time i read it, Thaks again !!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pyplot scatter plot marker size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14827650/pyplot-scatter-plot-marker-size)

Comment: totally... how to change it?