# Pandas & Matplot -> Independent marker out of scale

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a scatter chart where i the X-axis is the latitude, the Y-axis is the longitude. Each dot represents a restaurant. The marker size should represent the gross income of that restaurant.

In some areas these values vary wildly, in order of about 100x times, so these guys (rich ones) completely "hide" small nearby restaurants...

So I thought of using a log scale on the marker size... here is the code:

```
groups.plot.scatter(x='lon', y='lat', s=groups.weight.apply(lambda x: math.log(x)))

plt.plot(sLon, sLat, marker='o', color='red', markersize=math.log(aux.__len__()))
```

The thing is: i know for a fact that `aux.__len__()` equals several of the weights on the `groups`. Here is a image:

[image: plot]

The red dot should be very close in size to the ones on its right...

so my question is: Why is the plot from the second command not scaled as the rest?

Answer (score 0):

Its different because you are using `scatter` and `plot` which use different sizes. The markersize of `plot` scales linearly and is more sensitive than the `s` for a `scatter` which scales with the sqrt.

See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14827650/pyplot-scatter-plot-marker-size) for a similar discussion: