# How to draw a figure in specific pixel size with matplotlib?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Right now I'm working on a graphic project which requires me to draw a image that has specific element size in micrometer. And I'm using matplotlib to finish this task. However, I meet some problems in size control.

I've calculated all the plot data to describe the image. It basically is a grid with scatters on grid's cross line and there are hundreds of columns and rows in this grid and each axis for each cross line has its own width in micrometer as its size unit. Example image is just like this: [image: example]

I've tried many ways to control element or artist size. For making one pixel equals to one micrometer, I set a large DPI to the figure

```py
DPI = 25400
plt.figure(dpi=DPI)
fig = plt.gcf()
size = (
    width / DPI,
    height / DPI
)
fig.set_size_inches(size)
```

this can ensure that one pixel is one micrometer. 
However, I don't know how to control scatter and line width in pixel size.
the default `s` in `plt.scatter` or `linewidth` in `plt.plot` can't help to control the size.

I want to know how to control it in micrometers with matplotlib or should I just change another tool to draw this graph or even any other tools to meet this requirement?

Answer (score 6):

Matplotlib's linewidth is in points; scatter size is in points^2. For this see [pyplot scatter plot marker size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14827650/pyplot-scatter-plot-marker-size/47403507#47403507).

```
1 point == fig.dpi/72. pixels
```

Hence,

```
1 pixel == 72/fig.dpi points
```

If one micron is one pixel, and you want something of a size x microns,

```
x microns = x pixel = x*72 /fig.dpi points
```

hence

```
plt.plot(..., linewidth=x * 72 / fig.dpi)
plt.scatter(..., s=(x * 72 / fig.dpi)**2)
```

Comment: thanks dude! I have another question if you would like to help me out! Actually, I need to draw this image in a very small scale (less than 5cm) and draw each element in micron. However, each graph always seems larger than I expected. Then user can zoom in to check out the graph. I don't know how to  control this different size units and visual output units

Comment: I don't really understand the necessity to draw anything in actualy physical units. If you want to display something on screen and let the user zoom in it, this will change anyways. So one can use normal data units for everything.

Comment: ok, thx dude, for solving this requirement, I asked the client to use CAD instead of matplotlib to control the subtle unit size or whatever he likes.