# How to use pcolor (or imshow) to plot color mapped squares centered on each X,Y scatter point

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot, imshow

I have several thousand points with X,Y,C values (in numpy arrays).

I want each X,Y point to be plotted on a 2D image plot with a colored square around it (a box of size 40x40 units). Each X,Y point should be centered in the middle of the box. The colour of the box will be mapped according to the C value. The X,Y points are fairly randomly spaced. The points are arranged so that no boxes will overlap, they may touch, or have gaps.

I'm not a Python expert so would appreciate if someone could help get me started on this with a few lines of code. I believe that something like imshow or pcolor will be needed.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can simply set up the size and marker type in the [`scatter`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html) command.

That'd be my solution:

```py
X = 50 * np.round(10 * np.random.rand(100))
Y = 50 * np.round(10 * np.random.rand(100))
C = np.random.rand(100)

plt.figure(figsize=(12, 12))
sc = plt.scatter(X, Y, s=40**2, c=C, marker='s', cmap='gist_rainbow')
plt.scatter(X, Y, s=11**2, c='k')
plt.colorbar(sc)
plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```

The output would be the following:

[image: Output]

Hope that helps!

Comment: Yes, in fact that was my first solution. I can make nice plots using a marker of suitable size. But the problem is that although the box size will be  a constant for any particular plot (i.e. set of X,Y points) it won't always be 40x40. For example, another set of points to plot might have a box size of 25x25. In this case choosing an appropriate marker is cumbersome. Another thing is that the markers size would need to fill the entire 40x40 space, and because marker sizes are limited this would mean adjusting the size of the plot specifically for each marker size. So it's not very automated.

Comment: Ok, perhaps your code is setting the marker size to 40..which I didn't originally do...I'll give it a try...

Comment: You specify a marker size of 40**2...but I don't think this size is actually 40x40 units. On my plot using s=22 fills up the space between adjacent points (i.e. if they are separated by 40 units). So any marker size bigger than 22 will cause markers to be too big.

Comment: @Arg Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47403507/11089932) from [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14827650) (and linked references there), where the `s` parameter of `scatter` is extensively analyzed.

Comment: Thanks - I will look at that. Seems to be what I am after.