# plot differently sized scatters with the same space in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'd like to plot some equally spaced scatter with different size.

[image]

The "space" is shown in the dotted lines. However, since the size of the scatter is different, and the `x`, `y` params in the `ax.scatter` define the center of each sactter. I don't know how to control them. I think the key is to offset the radius length of the scatters with different size, but I don't know how to get it.
(**I have to use the `ax.scatter()` method for this**)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pyplot scatter plot marker size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14827650/pyplot-scatter-plot-marker-size)

Comment: @snwflk thanks I have to think about it. If you know a way, could you pls post an answer?

Comment: I think what you're trying to do will only every work for a single scale setting. As soon as you change the scaling, any such construction will no longer render equal distances, because the marker sizes are fixed (i.e. do not scale with the axes). Tbh, this question shouts XY problem at me. Who says you need to use `scatter`, which poses the main limitation? What is the context in which you require this?

Comment: @snwflk I think to make this simple is just to ask how do you plot a dotted line showing the radius of a scatter. Can you think of a way? I tried but it doesn't work and maybe I missed something here.