# How to adjust the marker size of a scatter plot, so that it matches a given radius? (Using matplotlib transformations)

Tags: python, matplotlib, transform, marker

I want to have the markers of a scatter plot match a radius given in the data coordinates.

I've read in [pyplot scatter plot marker size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14827650/pyplot-scatter-plot-marker-size), that the marker size is given as the area of the marker in points^2.

I tried transforming the given radius into points via `axes.transData` and then calculating the area via `pi * r^2`, but I did not succeed.

Maybe I did the transformation wrong.
It could also be that running matplotlib from WSL via VcXsrv is causing this problem.

Here is an example code of what I want to accomplish, with the results as an image below the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import pi

n = 16
# create a n x n square with a marker at each point
x_data = []
y_data = []
for x in range(n):
    for y in range(n):
        x_data.append(x)
        y_data.append(y)

fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=[7,7])

# important part:
# calculate the marker size so that the markers touch

# radius in data coordinates:
r = 0.5 
# radius in display coordinates:
r_ = ax.transData.transform([r,0])[0] - ax.transData.transform([0,0])[0]
# marker size as the area of a circle
marker_size = pi * r_**2

ax.scatter(x_data, y_data, s=marker_size, edgecolors='black')

plt.show()
```

When I run it with `s=r_` I get the result on the left and with `s=marker_size` I get the result on the right of the following image:
[image: Example]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code looks perfectly fine. You can see this if you plot just 4 points (`n=2`):

[image: 4 cricles]

The radius is (almost) exactly the `r=0.5` coordinate-units that you wanted to have. wait, *almost?!*
Yes, the problem is that you determine the coordinate-units-to-figure-points size before plotting, so *before* setting the limits, which influence the coordinate-units but not the overall figure size...

Sounded strange? Perhaps. The bottom line is that you determine the coordinate transformation with the default axis-limits (`(0,1)` x `(0,1)`) and enlarges them afterwards to `(-0.75, 15.75)`x`(-0.75, 15.75)`... but you are not reducing the marker-size.

So either set the limits to the known size *before* plotting:

```py
ax.set_xlim((0,n-1))
ax.set_ylim((0,n-1))
```

The complete code is:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import pi

n = 16
# create a n x n square with a marker at each point as dummy data
x_data = []
y_data = []
for x in range(n):
    for y in range(n):
        x_data.append(x)
        y_data.append(y)

# open figure
fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=[7,7])
# set limits BEFORE plotting
ax.set_xlim((0,n-1))
ax.set_ylim((0,n-1))
# radius in data coordinates:
r = 0.5 # units
# radius in display coordinates:
r_ = ax.transData.transform([r,0])[0] - ax.transData.transform([0,0])[0] # points
# marker size as the area of a circle
marker_size = pi * r_**2
# plot
ax.scatter(x_data, y_data, s=marker_size, edgecolors='black')

plt.show()
```

[image: output set limits]

... or scale the markers's size according to the new limits (you will need to know them or do the plotting again)

```py
# plot with invisible color
ax.scatter(x_data, y_data, s=marker_size, color=(0,0,0,0))
# calculate scaling
scl = ax.get_xlim()[1] - ax.get_xlim()[0]
# plot correctly (with color)
ax.scatter(x_data, y_data, s=marker_size/scl**2, edgecolors='blue',color='red')
```

This is a rather tedious idea, because you need to plot the data twice but you keep the autosizing of the axes...

[image: output with double plotting]

**There obviously remains some spacing.** This is due a misunderstanding of the *area* of the markers. We are not talking about the area of the symbol (in this case a circle) but of a bounding box of the marker (imagine, you want to control the size of a star or an asterix as marker... one would never calculate the actual area of the symbol).
So calculating the area is not `pi * r_**2` but rather a square: `(2*r_)**2`

```py
# open figure
fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=[7,7])
# setting the limits
ax.set_xlim((0,n-1))
ax.set_ylim((0,n-1))
# radius in data coordinates:
r = 0.5 # units
# radius in display coordinates:
r_ = ax.transData.transform([r,0])[0] - ax.transData.transform([0,0])[0] # points
# marker size as the area of a circle
marker_size = (2*r_)**2
# plot
ax.scatter(x_data, y_data, s=marker_size,linewidths=1)
#ax.plot(x_data, y_data, "o",markersize=2*r_)
plt.show()
```

[image: output (2*r)**2]
As soon as you add an edge (so a non-zero border around the markers), they will overlap:
[image: overlap]

If even gets more confusing if you use `plot` (which is faster if all markers should have the same size as the [docs](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html) state as "Notes"). The `markersize` is only the width (not the area) of the marker:

```py
ax.plot(x_data, y_data, "o",markersize=2*r_,color='magenta')
```

[image: plot command]

Comment: With setting the limits beforehand it works better but still not perfect. There are gaps in the pictures you posted. And if I run the exact code you posted I get this:
https://imgur.com/a/YZGIFKS

Comment: @NicoG. odd that you have an overlap where I didn't had one. Anyway, I searched the docs and found the solution, you need: it is the area of the marker, not of the symbol. And this area always is a square (I added the explanation & examples)

Comment: That makes sense. 
You made a spelling mistake. You wrote `(r*r_)**2` instead of `(2*r_)**2` in the explanation.

If I try this in a Jupyter Notebook I get the same result that you got. I still notice a difference in the x and y direction, but thats barely noticable.

But running it as a python file via WSL+VcXsrv I still get a wrong result. Since `pi=3.14` and `2*2=4` my new result has even more overlap. It could be that matplotlib does not get the right display coordinates, because it's a virtual machine. It could also be that `plt.show()` does some scaling, that I cannot account for.

Comment: good eyes, thx! I ran this as normal python-file with *matplotlib 3.3.1* (in VScode on Windows). Seems to be odd that you  get a different appearance

Comment: I somehow fixed it by multiplying the marker size with 0.5 . With this new information you gave me and the strange correction factor, it works in this example as well as in the actual project I wanted this code for. I'm really curious and confused why this is. Thx for your answers!