# Plot node size as legend using Networkx

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx

While working with NetworkX, I managed to plot a graph that shows the node size corresponding to a node attribute. To produce a consistent plot, I want to show the node size in the legend.
Is there a pre-implemented way to add a legend with a defined number (e.g., four) of node sizes with the corresponding node attribute?

I imagine something similar to the appended legend.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mvffv.png]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unsure of a built-in way to do this, but `networkx` plotting algorithm uses `scatter` to set node size so you can create a set of *ghost* nodes using scatter that are used in the legend. (I am making up the term *ghost* because you don't actually see them. There may be an officially accepted term, I don't know.)

For some reason I am could not get these to work with `scatter` so I am using `plot` instead. (Note that the size of values in `scatter` follows area while `plot` follows width [as discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14827650/pyplot-scatter-plot-marker-size) so the the size of the *ghost* values used in `plot` are the square-root of the sizes generated by `networkx.draw_networkx`.

```
from math import sqrt
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Create graph
G = nx.Graph()
N = 10 # number of nodes
for n in range(1,N + 1):
    G.add_node(n, size = n * 100, pos = [0, n]) # size of node based on its number

# Draw graph
node_sizes = nx.get_node_attributes(G, 'size')
nx.draw_networkx(G, node_color = 'b', node_size = [v for v in node_sizes.values()])

# Make legend
for n in [2, 4, 6, 8]:
    plt.plot([], [], 'bo', markersize = sqrt(n*100), label = f"{n}")
plt.legend(labelspacing = 5, loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5), frameon = False)
```

[image: graph]

Answer (score 0):

I have a bit of a hacky, alternative way of doing this, using scatter `legend_items`, basically making a scatter plot with your node sizes, copying the legend, then removing the scatter plot again. Probably neater way to to do this but it works.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx
from scipy.stats import expon

# some random graph
G = nx.erdos_renyi_graph(10, 0.5)

# some attribute that will influence node size
attribute = [70*i for i in range(10)]

# helper method for getting legend
def get_legend(sizes, num=10):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    sc = ax.scatter([0]*len(sizes), [0]*len(sizes), s=sizes, color='blue')
    store = sc.legend_elements("sizes", num=num)
    fig.clf()
    return store

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
nx.draw_networkx(G, node_size=attribute, ax=ax)
ax.legend(*get_legend(attribute, num=10), title="Variable A")
```

[image]