# Matplotlib output in Tkinter

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I am running the following script. The script has to generate a circle.

```
import pyplot as plt

circle1=plt.Circle((0.5,0.5),.2,color='g', fill=False)
fig=plt.gcf()
fig.gca().add_artist(circle1)
plt.show()
```

The output is as follows:

[image]

I want the output on a Tkinter canvas. How do I go about this?

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9215658/plot-a-circle-with-pyplot) question and the code given there wants me to import `matplotlib` but I do not need to import it.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16849483/which-is-the-recommended-way-to-plot-matplotlib-or-pylab/16849816#16849816

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the matplotlib examples:

http://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_tk.html

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')

from numpy import arange, sin, pi
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
# implement the default mpl key bindings
from matplotlib.backend_bases import key_press_handler


from matplotlib.figure import Figure

import sys
if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
    import Tkinter as Tk
else:
    import tkinter as Tk

root = Tk.Tk()
root.wm_title("Embedding in TK")


f = Figure(figsize=(5,4), dpi=100)
a = f.add_subplot(111)
t = arange(0.0,3.0,0.01)
s = sin(2*pi*t)

a.plot(t,s)


# a tk.DrawingArea
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, master=root)
canvas.show()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=Tk.TOP, fill=Tk.BOTH, expand=1)

toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg( canvas, root )
toolbar.update()
canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=Tk.TOP, fill=Tk.BOTH, expand=1)

def on_key_event(event):
    print('you pressed %s'%event.key)
    key_press_handler(event, canvas, toolbar)

canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', on_key_event)

def _quit():
    root.quit()     # stops mainloop
    root.destroy()  # this is necessary on Windows to prevent
                    # Fatal Python Error: PyEval_RestoreThread: NULL tstate

button = Tk.Button(master=root, text='Quit', command=_quit)
button.pack(side=Tk.BOTTOM)

Tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: This is similar to the link that I attached in the question, and that is precisely what I wanted to bypass.

Comment: why don't you want to import matplotlib? essentially you are via import pylab anyway. Its needed for all the canvas hooks into the different toolkits

Comment: I am just importing pyplot and it is working. Since I am running it on windows I guess the installation has made it easier...? I don't have to import matplotlib to make pyplot work.

Comment: it would do since importing pyplot imports alot to allow it to work, one of the 1st things the pyplot.py file imports is... matplotlib.

Comment: See I have installed matplotlib and pyplot. Whenever it needs to import pyplot and pyplot searches for matplotlib it finds it and then I am able to plot the graph without even importing matplotlib (I am serious, I don't know how it finds matplotlib and works without me properly importing it)

Comment: because pylab imports it at its namespace. Matplotlib ships with lots of modules, one is matplotlib.py, the main package. There are others which are either imported as an when or in the instance of pyplot.py, a module which is a convenience wrapper for quick plots. I use pyplot alot to quickly plot data BUT todo anything more useful than just plot(x,y) other aspects of Matplotlib are needed

Comment: So I need to import matplotlib and then start with the example?

Comment: please just try the example

Comment: Okay okay I will if you say so. :D