# How to draw circle by data with matplotlib + python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I can draw a circle by `scatter`, which has been shown in the image. But I want to draw them buy a line, because there are many circles in total, I need to link nodes together for a certain circle. Thanks.
[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [plot a circle with pyplot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9215658/plot-a-circle-with-pyplot)

Comment: What does your data look like? Why do you want to use `scatter`

Comment: @holdenweb My data is the coordinates of dots.

Comment: @Ben My data is the coordinates of dots. Or what I need is 'closed curve'. Not circle exactly.

Comment: So you want to FIT a circle to your data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I the order of the points is random, you can change X-Y to polar, and sort the data by angle:

create some random order points first:

```
import pylab as pl
import numpy as np

angle = np.arange(0, np.pi*2, 0.05)
r = 50 + np.random.normal(0, 2, angle.shape)

x = r * np.cos(angle)
y = r * np.sin(angle)

idx = np.random.permutation(angle.shape[0])
x = x[idx]
y = y[idx]
```

Then use `arctan2()` to calculate the angle, and sort the data by it:

```
angle = np.arctan2(x, y)
order = np.argsort(angle)
x = x[order]
y = y[order]

fig, ax = pl.subplots()
ax.set_aspect(1.0)
x2 = np.r_[x, x[0]]
y2 = np.r_[y, y[0]]
ax.plot(x, y, "o")
ax.plot(x2, y2, "r", lw=2)
```

here is the output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it.  This answer uses different methods than the linked [possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9215658/plot-a-circle-with-pyplot), so may be worth keeping.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import patches

fig = plt.figure(figsize=plt.figaspect(1.0))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

cen = (2.0,1.0); r = 3.0
circle = patches.Circle(cen, r, facecolor='none')
ax.add_patch(circle)
ax.set_xlim(-6.0, 6.0)
ax.set_ylim(-6.0, 6.0)
```

If all you have are the `x` and `y` points, you can use `PathPatch`.  Here's a [tutorial](http://matplotlib.org/users/path_tutorial.html)

Comment: my data is the coordinate of the dots on a edge of a circle, or like a circle. Not exactly circles. Maybe what I need is 'closed curves'. Not circle.

Comment: I feel path is not applicable. Coz I need to give out all the vertex and the numbering. That is too much job.

Comment: do you want to just plot them?  how are the points ordered in your arrays.  if they go in order around the circle just use `plt.plot( x,y )`

Comment: if they are not ordered you could sort the left half in increasing y and the right have in decreasing y to get them in the right order

Answer (score 0):

If your data points are already in order, the `plot` command should work fine. If you're looking to generate a circle from scratch, you can use a parametric equation.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> t = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi, 100)
>>> x = np.cos(t)
>>> y = np.sin(t)
>>> plt.plot(x,y)
```