# Error in Plotting circle for Similarity measure using matplotlib in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, visualization

I am working on project to find similarity between two sentences/documents using tf-idf measure.

Now my question is how can I show the similarity in a graphical/Visualization format. Something like a Venn diagram where intersection value becomes the similarity measure or any other plots available in matplotlib or any python libraries.

I tried the following code:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity  

documents = (
"The sky is blue",
"The sun is bright"

)
tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
tfidf_matrix = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(documents)
print tfidf_matrix
cosine = cosine_similarity(tfidf_matrix[0:1], tfidf_matrix)
print cosine
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
r=25
d1 = 2 * r * (1 - cosine[0][0])
circle1=plt.Circle((0,0),d1/2,color='r')
d2 = 2 * r * (1 - cosine[0][1])
circle2=plt.Circle((r,0),d2/2,color="b")
fig = plt.gcf()
fig.gca().add_artist(circle1)
fig.gca().add_artist(circle2)
fig.savefig('plotcircles.png')
plt.show()
```

But the plot I got was empty. Can some one explain what might be the error.

plotting circle source:[plot a circle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9215658/plot-a-circle-with-pyplot)

Comment: If you look at the axes of the figure, and then print the values for d1, d2 and r, you'll quickly notice that the first circle has a diameter of 0 (at least, when I ran this code), and the second one falls completely outside the graph borders.

Comment: Adding the following just before `savefig` can fix this, though I guess there are better ways (and, of course, this won't show the circle with 0 radius anyway): `fig.axes[0].axis([min(-d1/2, r-d2/2), max(d1, r+d2/2), min(-d1/2, -d2/2), max(d1/2, d2/2)])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Plots are not empty, but I guess, your circles are to big!

I don't have sklearn installed, so I start at the point where you `print cosine`:

```
## set constants
r = 1
d = 2 * r * (1 - cosine[0][1])

## draw circles
circle1=plt.Circle((0, 0), r, alpha=.5)
circle2=plt.Circle((d, 0), r, alpha=.5)
## set axis limits
plt.ylim([-1.1, 1.1])
plt.xlim([-1.1, 1.1 + d])
fig = plt.gcf()
fig.gca().add_artist(circle1)
fig.gca().add_artist(circle2)
## hide axes if you like
# fig.gca().get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
# fig.gca().get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
fig.savefig('venn_diagramm.png')
```

That also answers your other question, where I also added this piece of code!

Answer (score 4):

Just to explain what's going on, here's a stand-alone example of your problem (if the circle is entirely outside the boundaries, nothing would be shown):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Circle

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
circ = Circle((1, 1), 0.5)
ax.add_artist(circ)
plt.show()
```

[image]

When you manually add an artist through `add_artist`, `add_patch`, etc, autoscaling isn't applied unless you explicitly do so. You're accessing a lower-level interface of matplotlib that's what the higher-level functions (e.g. `plot`) are built on top of.  However, this is also the easiest way to add a single circle in data coordinates, so the lower-level interface is what you want in this case.

Furthermore, `add_artist` is too general for this.  You actually want `add_patch` (`plt.Circle` is `matplotlib.patches.Circle`).  The difference between `add_artist` and `add_patch` may seem arbitrary, but `add_patch` has extra logic to calculate the extent of a patch for autoscaling, whereas `add_artist` is the "bare" lower-level function that can take any artist, but doesn't do anything special. Autoscaling won't work correctly for a patch if you add it with `add_artist`.

To autoscale the plot based on the artists that you've added, call `ax.autoscale()`:

As a quick example of autoscaling a manually added patch:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Circle

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
circ = Circle((1, 1), 0.5)
ax.add_patch(circ)
ax.autoscale()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Your next question might be "why isn't the circle round?".  It is, in data coordinates.  However, the x and y scales of the plot (this is the aspect ratio, in matplotlib terminology) are currently different.  To force them to be the same, call `ax.axis('equal')` or `ax.axis('scaled')`. (We can actually leave out the call to `autoscale` in this case, as `ax.axis('scaled'/'equal')` will effectively call it for us.):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Circle

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
circ = Circle((1, 1), 0.5)
ax.add_patch(circ)
ax.axis('scaled')
plt.show()
```

[image]