# Give 3 points and a plot circle

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I want to give the points [0,1],[1,0] and [0,-1] to python and plot the circle that passes over them. Does exists a python module that make this? I have tried using matplotlib:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([0,1,0],[1,0,-1])
plt.show()
```

But only gave me two lines.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There was a "code golf" question exactly matching this (except that the circle's equation was requested, rather than plotting it) -- see https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2289/circle-through-three-points .  Unraveling the first and shortest (Python) solution into more readable, less-hacky form to match your exact specs - but keeping the core idea of using complex numbers for simpler calculations:

```
x, y, z = 0+1j, 1+0j, 0-1j
w = z-x
w /= y-x
c = (x-y)*(w-abs(w)**2)/2j/w.imag-x
print '(x%+.3f)^2+(y%+.3f)^2 = %.3f^2' % (c.real, c.imag, abs(c+x))
```

OK, this still "prints the equation" rather than "plotting the circle", but, we're getting close:-).  To actually **plot** the circle in `matplotlib`, see e.g [plot a circle with pyplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9215658/plot-a-circle-with-pyplot) -- in the solution above, `c` is the (negated) center of the circle (as a complex number, so use .real and .imag for the x/y coordinates), and `abs(c+x)` the radius (a real number, `abs` makes it so).

Comment: This is the useful one because I will work with complex numbers. I forgot that it's easier to obtain the center and radius by this way.

Comment: I guess seeing your nick clearly honoring Évariste Galois guided my subconscious towards this mathematically elegant idea:-).  Remembering a guy who died at 1/3rd my age, leaving behind just 60 pages of notes revolutionizing **two** key branches of maths, keeps me appropriately humble (plus, I'm 1/8th French, so it also helps keep me appropriately proud:-).

Comment: Is nice to see a person that knows of him. I'm an algebra lover because of his discoveries :-).

Comment: Perfect! And if your input is in Cartesian, first convert the 3 points to complex coordinates, e.g.:
`x, y, z = complex(2,2), complex(6,2), complex(2,6)`

Comment: What is the explanation of the math here? It seems to me like it's not exactly the same as [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1145021/281166) and I don't fully get it yet

Comment: @iam_agf I know this is six years old, but do you maybe still get it? I find the solution here very elegant, but I did not manage to understand it now despite investing a few hours. I assume it should be obvious once one gets it?

Comment: I don't remember if at some point I reached to understand how he did it, since, as how he said, he adapted a solution from a code golf question, but I remember I looked for my own way to calculate it because the only thing that lighted me up was the phrase "complex numbers". In fact I consider easier your link posted since it's explained in an extended way.

Comment: @iam_agf I got it now! I added an explanation in my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66518545/2550406) to make life easier for future visitors.

Answer (score 18):

This code also lets you easily check whether the 3 points form a line or not.

```
def define_circle(p1, p2, p3):
    """
    Returns the center and radius of the circle passing the given 3 points.
    In case the 3 points form a line, returns (None, infinity).
    """
    temp = p2[0] * p2[0] + p2[1] * p2[1]
    bc = (p1[0] * p1[0] + p1[1] * p1[1] - temp) / 2
    cd = (temp - p3[0] * p3[0] - p3[1] * p3[1]) / 2
    det = (p1[0] - p2[0]) * (p2[1] - p3[1]) - (p2[0] - p3[0]) * (p1[1] - p2[1])
    
    if abs(det) < 1.0e-6:
        return (None, np.inf)
    
    # Center of circle
    cx = (bc*(p2[1] - p3[1]) - cd*(p1[1] - p2[1])) / det
    cy = ((p1[0] - p2[0]) * cd - (p2[0] - p3[0]) * bc) / det
    
    radius = np.sqrt((cx - p1[0])**2 + (cy - p1[1])**2)
    return ((cx, cy), radius)
```

And to solve the original question:

```
center, radius = define_circle((0,1), (1,0), (0,-1))
if center is not None:
    plt.figure(figsize=(4, 4))
    circle = plt.Circle(center, radius)
    plt.gcf().gca().add_artist(circle)
```

(Adjusted from [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20171223103555/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/54323.html))

Answer (score 4):

I was *very* curious why the [accepted answer by Alex Martelli](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28910804/2550406) works. And I had to create a report for my lecture anyway, so I'm pasting it here for posterity.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Nice job solving the algebra, and thanks for adding this as part of the solutions :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think I might have spotted a mistake in equation 14 though. Shouldn’t it be „+ p1“ instead of „+ x“ in the end?

Comment: @FlixMa that sounds plausible. I probably typed that wrong because my `p1` is the accepted answer's `x`.

Answer (score 2):

Given three points whose coordinates are:

(p,t) (q,u) (s,z)

...the equation of the circle defined by those three points is:

x^2 + y^2 + A*x + B*y + C = 0

where:

```
A=((u-t)*z^2+(-u^2+t^2-q^2+p^2)*z+t*u^2+(-t^2+s^2-p^2)*u+(q^2-s^2)*t)/((q-p)*z+(p-s)*u+(s-q)*t)

B=-((q-p)*z^2+(p-s)*u^2+(s-q)*t^2+(q-p)*s^2+(p^2-q^2)*s+p*q^2-p^2*q)/((q-p)*z+(p-s)*u+(s-q)*t)

C=-((p*u-q*t)*z^2+(-p*u^2+q*t^2-p*q^2+p^2*q)*z+s*t*u^2+(-s*t^2+p*s^2-p^2*s)*u+(q^2*s-q*s^2)*t)/((q-p)*z+(p-s)*u+(s-q)*t)
```

The above is the general solution.  You can put the formulas for A, B, and C into your program
and find the equation for any circle, given 3 points.

For your particular problem with points (0,1) (1,0) (0,-1) you will get:

A=0

B=0

C=-1

... so the equation will be

x^2 + y^2 -1 = 0  (the unit circle)

Answer (score 1):

To draw a circle in matplotlib, first you need to declare an artist

```
circle = plt.Circle((0,0), 2)
```

you then have to add that artist to an instance of axes:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.add_artist(circle)
```

then you can draw it safely.

```
plt.show()
```

Notice that artist `Circle` takes `(x,y)` coordinates of the circle's center, and radius `r`. That means you're going to have to calculate those values yourself.