# Calculate circle given 3 points (code explanation)

Tags: python, math, 2d, geometry

When searching for code to calculate the circle out of 3 points it leads me to this code:

```
def circleRadius(b, c, d):
  temp = c[0]**2 + c[1]**2
  bc = (b[0]**2 + b[1]**2 - temp) / 2
  cd = (temp - d[0]**2 - d[1]**2) / 2
  det = (b[0] - c[0]) * (c[1] - d[1]) - (c[0] - d[0]) * (b[1] - c[1])

  if abs(det) < 1.0e-10:
    return None

  # Center of circle
  cx = (bc*(c[1] - d[1]) - cd*(b[1] - c[1])) / det
  cy = ((b[0] - c[0]) * cd - (c[0] - d[0]) * bc) / det

  radius = ((cx - b[0])**2 + (cy - b[1])**2)**.5

  return radius
```

Based on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28910718/give-3-points-and-a-plot-circle) and [Dr.Math](https://web.archive.org/web/20171223103555/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/54323.html). The code works perfectly, but I don't understand how the code fits to the explanation given at [Dr.Math](https://web.archive.org/web/20171223103555/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/54323.html).

Can anyone help me to understand why the code is working and what substeps are implemented in the variables?

Comment: It computes the intersection of the perpendicular bisectors of the lines `BC` and `CD`. There's a fair amount of algebra involved but it is not too hard to prove – only requires grade-school geometry.

Comment: But where does it calculate the perpendicular bisectors. BC and CD are values and no points and of what do I calculate the determinante (to determine the slope?) and how do they come together at cx,cy? I do understand the principle idea behind this approach, but can't map the steps in code to it...

Comment: If you "de-compress" this code into the relevant steps it boils down to the following: **1)** compute the midpoints of `BC` and `CD`; **2)** calculate the perpendicular directions to `BC` and `CD`; **3)** use the results of (1) and (2) to define the perpendicular bisector lines; **4)** solve a pair of simultaneous equations to obtain the intersection point coordinates – this is where the determinant is used. Work out these variables, do a bunch of tedious algebra to simplify, and you get the equations in the code above.

Comment: What is the value of variable bc and dc and where does the slope come from? To calculate (1) I would suggest code like BC = ((B[0]+C[0])/2, (B[1],C[1])/2) and (2) with -1/(slope of BC)... but where does this calculation take place?

Comment: @Seppelandrio Forget about slopes. Rather simple math description for intersection point: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_(Euclidean_geometry)#On_a_plane

Answer (score 1):

The code you see is a "simplified" and concise formula of the procedure described in the Dr. Math page.

Let us go over it step-by-step.

1. For the sake of simplicity and adhering to mathematical notations, let [image: points] be the points on the triangle. [b is point 1, c is point 2, and d is point 3]
2. For such triangle, the area is defined as:

   [image: area]

   This variable `det` in the function is equal to 2 * area of the triangle.

   The `if abs(det) < 1.0e-10:` is checking for collinearity. If the area is close to zero, the points given are collinear i.e. they are points on a single line.
3. Find the slopes of the lines L1, L2 passing through points b, c & c, d

   [image: slope]
4. Find the equations for lines *L3*, *L4*, which are the perpendicular bisectors of line s*L1* and *L2* respectively.
   [image: bisectors1]
   [image: bisectors2]
5. Find the intersection of lines *L3* and *L4*, which is nothing but the center of the cirle.

   [image: intersection]

Do all the substitutions and you can see it all come together.

6. Compute radius of the circle by finding the euclidean distance between the center and one of the three points.

Comment: What are you going to do if `y1=y2 or y3=y2 or x2=x1` etc?

Comment: Thank you! So I understood the term!

Comment: @MBo, After all the variables, are substituted, the difference terms causing a divide by zero will be eliminated. That is evident in the formula used to calculate `cx` and `cy`.

I think *divide by zero* is the reason this specific piece of code does not calculate slopes. By avoiding calculating slopes beforehand, we can avert that catastrophic divide/multiply by zero problems.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer, I am showing here an alternative method.

Let `p`, `q`, `r` be the three points. We translate them so that `p` comes to the origin. Vectorially, `q-= p`, `r-= p`.

Now the equation of a point by the origin is

```
2.xc.x + 2.yc.y = x² + y²
```

where `xc`, `yc` are the coordinates of the center.

The plugging the coordinates of `p`, `q`, we get a 2x2 system

```
xc.xp + yc.yp = xp² + yp²
xc.xq + yc.yq = xq² + yq²
```

The code that implements this is given below

```
# Translate to the origin
xq-= xp
yq-= yp
q2= xp * xp + yp * yp
xr-= xq
yr-= yq
r2= xr * xr + yr * yr

# Solve for the center coordinates
d= 2 * (xp * yq - xq * yp)
xc= (p2 * yq - q2 * yp) / d
yc= (p2 * xp - q2 * xq) / d

# Radius
r= math.sqrt(xc * xc + yc * yc)

# Untranslate
xc+= xp
yc+= yp
```