# How to create a circle?

Tags: python

I have to create a charge distribution of circular shape. I already created a square charge distribution and it look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnYGP.png). How can I change this square distribution to circular?

My code for the square distribution:

```
Nmax = 120; Niter = 10
V = zeros((Nmax, Nmax+100)  , float)
for k in range(0, 40): V[40+k,40] = 2400.0
for k in range(0, 40): V[40,k+40] = 2400.0
for k in range(0, 40): V[80,k+40] = 2400.0
for k in range(0, 40): V[40+k,80] = 2400.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
from math import sin, cos, pi
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x,y = [cos((i*pi)/500) for i in range(1000)], [sin((i*pi)/500) for i in range(1000)]
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

Or use the circle function from matplotlib, as demonstrated in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9215658/plot-a-circle-with-pyplot).

Comment: use `[r*cos((i*pi)/500) for i in range(1000)], [r*sin((i*pi)/500) for i in range(1000)]` where `r` is the radius you want :)