# Matplotlib figure does not close after being resurrected

Tags: python, matplotlib, figure

Try the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure() #creates a pyplot figure
plt.close(fig) #closes the figure
fig.show() #resurrects the figure, that is, displays it
plt.close(fig) #should close the figure, but does nothing
```

My questions are:

1. why does not the last line of code close the figure ?
2. how to get the figure closed anyway (programmatically) after it has been  resurrected as above ?

Comment: I think that calling `close` actually destroys any underlying resources used by the figure and prevents all operations from working. The default backend allows the window to be shown after it dies in your case. Try `fig, ax = plt.subplots(); ax.plot(...); fig.show(); plt.close(fig); ax.plot(...); fig.show();`. Only the first thing you plot will show up. After that, all the methods will do nothing because the backend is destroyed.

Comment: I had a similar problem once, creating multiple plots which weren't closed or deleted properly. I solved it by assigning None to plt. plt = None or in your case fig = None.
May not be the best solution but kept matplotlib from plotting multiple plots in one plot.

Comment: @Mad Physicist  You are right. I thought that closing the figure manually using the x button is the same as plt.close(fig). But this behaves differently. I will delete this question in 1-2 days, and post another question related to the x button.

Comment: I don't think you should delete the question. It is actually pretty good. I am hoping that one of the real matplotlib gurus like @tcaswell shows up with a proper explanation. I am curious to hear the details.