# Plotting a circle in leaflet using .add_artist()

Tags: python, matplotlib, leaflet, plotly

Starting from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9215658/plot-a-circle-with-pyplot#) and the first example from [here](https://github.com/jwass/mplleaflet), I'm trying to use `pyplot` and `mplleaflet` to plot a *fixed-size* circle on a map.

(By "fixed-size", I mean that this circle is not a marker, it shouldn't adapt to the zoom level, but should stay of, say, 25m diameter whatever the zoom level).

Here is what I got :

```
import mplleaflet
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x = 2.363561
y = 48.951918
r = 20
circle1 = mpl.patches.Circle((x,y), radius=r)
circle2= plt.Circle((x, y), r, color='r')

ax.add_artist(circle1)
ax.add_artist(circle2)

mplleaflet.show(fig=ax.figure)
```

Code runs fine, but when the new leaflet tab opens, I got nothing :

[image]