# Can't display patches with mplleaflet

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, leaflet, plotly

I'm trying to display a circle of fixed size in a leaflet map.

I tried with `.add_artist()`(see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46305778/plotting-a-circle-in-leaflet-using-add-artist)) and I'm now trying with `.add_patch()`

```
import mplleaflet
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x = 2.363561
y = 48.951918
r = 20
circle1 = mpl.patches.Circle((x,y), radius=r)
circle2= plt.Circle((x, y), r, color='r')

#ax.add_patch(circle1)
#ax.add_patch(circle2) 

mplleaflet.show(fig=ax.figure)
```

You can try to uncomment one of the two commented lines, it doesn't matter which line is uncommented, same error pops.

Here is the trace I get :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-81-1fdd7f4a9d12>", line 16, in <module>
    mplleaflet.show(fig = ax.figure)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mplleaflet\_display.py", line 180, in show
    save_html(fig, fileobj=f, **kwargs)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mplleaflet\_display.py", line 131, in save_html
    html = fig_to_html(fig, **kwargs)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mplleaflet\_display.py", line 84, in fig_to_html
    exporter.run(fig)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mplleaflet\mplexporter\exporter.py", line 51, in run
    self.crawl_fig(fig)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mplleaflet\mplexporter\exporter.py", line 118, in crawl_fig
    self.crawl_ax(ax)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mplleaflet\mplexporter\exporter.py", line 138, in crawl_ax
    self.draw_patch(ax, patch)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mplleaflet\mplexporter\exporter.py", line 227, in draw_patch
    mplobj=patch)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mplleaflet\leaflet_renderer.py", line 125, in draw_path
    rings = list(iter_rings(data, pathcodes))

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mplleaflet\utils.py", line 14, in iter_rings
    raise ValueError('Unrecognized code: {}'.format(code))

ValueError: Unrecognized code: C
```

Any idea on how to solve this ?

===========================

**EDIT :**

Just to see what would happen, I tried doing the same thing than [this](https://github.com/jwass/mplleaflet/issues/40#issuecomment-327276786), which is changing

```
elif code == 'L': ring.append(point)
```

to

```
elif code == 'L' or code == 'Z' or code == 'S' or code == 'C': ring.append(point)
```

in `mplleaflet\utils.py`, line 11 and 12. Here is what I got :

[image]

===========================

**EDIT 2 to answer comment**

`mpl.patches.Rectangle` and `plt.Rectangle` show up :

```
rect1 = mpl.patches.Rectangle((x,y), 1, 1, color = 'r')
rect2 = plt.Rectangle((x, y), 1, 1, fc='r')
```

[image]

Which seems to fit with a rectangle of 1 degree in latitude and 1 degree longitude (see [here](http://drh2.img.digitalriver.com/DRHM/Storefront/Company/digiwis/images/product/detail/fr2_0117.jpg)) (maybe ? Seems a bit small).

As for `Polygons`, well... At least they show up, but I guess there is a projection problem :

```
regpol1 = mpl.patches.RegularPolygon((x,y), 100, radius=r, color = 'r')
cirpol1 = mpl.patches.CirclePolygon((x +50,y), radius=r, color = 'b')
```

[image]

Comment: Is this a problem of the `Circle` or are different patches like `Rectangle` or `Polygon` also causing this error?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest See edit 2 to answer your question.