# Drawing true filled circle on an image

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, geometry, scikit-image

I have an image which I define like the following:

`img = np.zeros(474,474)`

I would like to draw true filled circles and not polygonal approximations of circles on this image at different coordinates as centre and of a fixed radius. For example, I want to draw two circles with centres `(100,200)` and `(150,372)` with radius `2` pixels. What I am expecting is that after plotting the circles, the entries of the original image `img` should change to all ones where the circle is present. 
I tried opencv `cv.circle`module as well as `skimage.draw.circle` module but they generate some polynomial approximation of circle. 
I was also trying the following in `matplotlib` but I don't seem to understand how to plot it on my image `img`. 
Any help would be appreciated.

```
from matplotlib.patches import Circle
img=np.zeros(474,474)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
centers = [(100,200),(150,372)]
for i in range(len(centers)):
    Circle((centers[i][0],centers[i][1]), radius= 2)
```

Comment: Can you post the full code?!

Comment: @Venkatesh This is all I have for code. It defines an image and I am trying to plot circles on my image using `matplotlib circle` module

Comment: In opencv, you have different parameters when drawing a circle for the lineType, that define the number of connected pixels that should be colored. You can try them out and define if it fits your needs. For instance, -1 will filled the circle.

Comment: @Crapsy Which implementation are you referring to? Can you please elaborate possibly with a code? Also, I am looking for a true filled circle

Comment: Most of the question text is quite unclear. Any circle is an approximation to a true circle. In any case, how to add a circle to a plot is shown in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9215658/plot-a-circle-with-pyplot). So I guess we might close this as duplicate or you clearly need to state in how far this does not help you here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When drawing a circle in OpenCV, there are several parameters that can be chosen, one of them is used to define the type of the circle boundary, you have 4 types:

- Filled
- 4-connected line
- 8-connected line
- antialiased line

You can see the different effect on the following image (in same order)
[image]

An example code (in C++)

```
circle(src,cv::Point(300,300), 10, Scalar(0,0,255), 1, FILLED);
```

Answer (score 4):

draw circles in the img.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = np.zeros([474, 474])

cv2.circle(img, (100,100), 5, 255, -1)
cv2.circle(img, (200,200), 30, 255, -1)

cv2.imshow('image', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```