# python/mathplotlib plot equivalent of R's symbol plot?

Tags: python, r, matplotlib, plot

Is there a python equivalent of this?

> symbols        package:graphics       R Documentation
>
> Draw Symbols (Circles, Squares, Stars, Thermometers, Boxplots)
>
> Description:
>
> This function draws symbols on a plot.  One of six symbols;
>     *circles*, *squares*, *rectangles*, *stars*, *thermometers*, and
>     *boxplots*, can be plotted at a specified set of x and y
>     coordinates.  Specific aspects of the symbols, such as relative
>     size, can be customized by additional parameters.

Comment: If by python you mean using matplotlib, you can use a `scatter` plot. For boxplots use a `boxplot` though, and for thermometers... not sure how that would look like, but if there is a unicode symbol of it, it can be plotted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can plot a circle of specific size at a given point using

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
circle=plt.Circle((0,0),.2,color='r')
plt.add_artist(circle)
```

The format is `Circle(x, y), radius)` where `x` and `y` are the position of the center in the plot. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9215658/plot-a-circle-with-pyplot) for more detail and explanation.

A rectangle (or square) of given size with

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches

rect = patches.Rectangle((50,100),40,30,facecolor='none')
plt.gca().add_patch(rect)
```

The format is `Rectangle((x, y), w, h)` where `x` and `y` are the coordinates in the plot of the top-left corner, `w` is the width and `h` is the height.

You can make an arbitrary polygon (i.e. a star) using

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches

poly = patches.Polygon(points, facecolor='None')
plt.gca().add_patch(poly)
```

Where `points` is an `numpy` array of shape `Nx2` (where `N` is the number of points) of the vertices of the polygon. More information (including keyword arguments) is available on the matplotlib docs for [polygon](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Polygon.html) and [rectangle](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Rectangle.html). I you just want those symbols as markers you can simply do

```
plt.scatter(x, y, marker='*')
```

Where `x` and `y` are arrays or array-like of the coordinates at which you want the markers. The marker used can be specified according to the matplotlib [markers](https://matplotlib.org/api/markers_api.html) docs. You can also draw a custom marker by supplying a `path` to draw, similar to how the `polygon` is drawn.

Comment: Isn't the real question how to plot thermometers?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I don't see where the OP specified which symbol they are interested in. I included the `polygon` method and the note about custom markers as possible ways a 'thermometer' could be drawn, I'm not aware of any better way to do it - though I am sure it exists.

Comment: The list of symbols they ask for is *circles, squares, rectangles, stars, thermometers, and boxplots*. Now there exist Stackoverflow answers for every item in that list, except for "thermomenter". Hence the only on-topic, non-duplicate question here would be how to plot thermometers, right?

Comment: I'm getting an error:
`>>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`
`>>> import matplotlib.patches as patches`
`>>> rect = patches.Rectangle((50,100),40,30,facecolor='none')`
`>>> plt.add_patch(rect)`
`Traceback (most recent call last):`
`  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>`
`AttributeError: module 'matplotlib.pyplot' has no attribute 'add_patch'`

Comment: @SteveDutky Ah yes, you need an axis handle for `add_patch`, my bad. See the edited solution

Comment: The real question about thermometers is now [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54790467/how-to-plot-a-thermometer).