# How do I visualize the output of K-modes clustering algorithm in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, matplotlib, scikit-learn, visualization

I have the output of the cluster details as shown below.

```
from collections import Counter, defaultdict
print(Counter(kmodess.labels_))
```

Output is the cluster number and number of users belonging to it: 
`Counter({1: 10500, 2: 400, 3:10})`

I want to show something like below. Is this possible in Python or if I have to use javascript, how do I proceed with this kind of representation?

[image]

I have refered the code from the below matplot.lib link. [plot a circle with pyplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9215658/plot-a-circle-with-pyplot)

But, how do I give the input and show the circles based on that?

Answer (score 0):

If you already know how to do this with pyplot you could save it to a file and serve that statically, no js required.

To dump your plot to a file:

```
plt.savefig('clusters.png')
```

Then use an HTML img tag:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Display my Matplotlib Image</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img src="clusters.png" alt="Large and small circles representing clusters">
  </body>
</html>
```

To see the result, just open the above html file with your browser.

Comment: I tried matplotlib.pyplot. I found a way to represent this using a piechart rather than seperate circles. Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I found the best way to represent such diagrams using piechart. 
Below is the link
https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/pie_and_polar_charts/pie_and_donut_labels.html#sphx-glr-gallery-pie-and-polar-charts-pie-and-donut-labels-py