# Background color index by radius on a graph in python

Tags: python, plot, scatter-plot

I'm trying to index something based on its distance from the origin. It's a scatter graph with color radians, in a way, where the background needs to be mapped. Kinda like this:
[image]
Is there any way to fill in the spaces, so to speak?

Comment: What do you mean by "fill in the spaces"? Like this? https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYXUE.png

Comment: Yes, exactly like that!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [plot a circle with pyplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9215658/plot-a-circle-with-pyplot) If you share your code that creates the plot you showed, maybe people can give more specific help, but the general idea is that you plot circles from out to in and then set the x and y limits of the axes