# hatched rectangle patches without edges in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, patch, hatchstyle

When trying to add a rectangle patch with a hatch pattern to a plot it seems that it is impossible to set the keyword argument edgecolor to 'none' when also specifying a hatch value.
In other words I am trying to add a hatched rectangle WITHOUT an edge but WITH a pattern filling. This doesnt seem to work. The pattern only shows up if I also allow an edge to be drawn around the rectangle patch.

Any help on how to achieve the desired behaviour?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should use the `linewidth` argument, which has to be set to zero.

Example (based on [your other question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18390068/hatch-a-nan-region-in-a-contourplot-in-matplotlib/18403408#18403408)):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

# generate some data:
x,y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(0,1),np.linspace(0,1))
z = np.ma.masked_array(x**2-y**2,mask=y>-x+1)

# plot your masked array
ax.contourf(z)

# plot a patch
p = patches.Rectangle((20,20), 20, 20, linewidth=0, fill=None, hatch='///')
ax.add_patch(p)
plt.show()
```

You'll get this image:
[image]

Comment: Can you control the linewidth of the hatch effect without increasing the border size?

Comment: The argument `linewidth` controls the width of the border only. According to the comments in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14325773/how-to-change-marker-border-width-and-hatch-width), it is not possible to control the linewidth of the hatch effect.

Comment: @jkokorian and anyone else arriving here:
There is a working solution to controlling linewidth of the hatch effect via rcParams here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56675011/13917918