# Choosing marker size in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I am doing a scatter plot with square marker in matplotlib like this one:

[image: small_marker].

I want to achieve something like this:

[image]

Which means I have to adjust the marker size and the figure size/ratio in such a way that there are no white space between markers. Also there should be a marker per index unit (*x* and *y* are both integers) so if *y* goes from 60 to 100, there should be 40 markers in *y* direction. At the moment I am tuning it manually. Any idea on what is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Use `plt.imshow` or `plt.pcolor` instead!

Comment: Fill your empty data positions with `np.nan` or use a masked array.  How the colormap handles bad values is controlled with `set_bad`

Comment: @tcaswell, I dont have empty data

Comment: What are the spaces in your graph without a marker then?

Comment: @DavidZwicker, with plt.imshow  or plt.color I will have to make transformations to my data(take it to 2D form). I could as well figure out the figure/marker size in my plot, and so I don't have to change my code.

Comment: @tcaswell, you are right but that doesn't represent a problem in my case. I thought you meant the empty white space between the markers.

Comment: but if you were to re-structure your data to use `imshow` that is how to handle the empty spaces.  If you really don't want to do it the easy way, I would just draw each patch yourself.  See `patch.Rectangle` and `patchCollection`.

Comment: `plt.pcolormesh` seems to be the best option for filled coloration of unstructured grids

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found two ways to go about this:

The first is based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13662525/how-to-get-pixel-coordinates-for-matplotlib-generated-scatterplot/13662938#13662938). Basically, you determine the number of pixels between the adjacent data-points and use it to set the marker size. The marker size in `scatter` is given as area.

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, aspect='equal')

# initialize a plot to determine the distance between the data points in pixel:    
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 3]
y = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2]
s = 0.0
points = ax.scatter(x,y,s=s,marker='s')
ax.axis([min(x)-1., max(x)+1., min(y)-1., max(y)+1.])

# retrieve the pixel information:
xy_pixels = ax.transData.transform(np.vstack([x,y]).T)
xpix, ypix = xy_pixels.T

# In matplotlib, 0,0 is the lower left corner, whereas it's usually the upper 
# right for most image software, so we'll flip the y-coords
width, height = fig.canvas.get_width_height()
ypix = height - ypix

# this assumes that your data-points are equally spaced
s1 = xpix[1]-xpix[0]

points = ax.scatter(x,y,s=s1**2.,marker='s',edgecolors='none')
ax.axis([min(x)-1., max(x)+1., min(y)-1., max(y)+1.])

fig.savefig('test.png', dpi=fig.dpi)
```

The downside of this first approach is, that the symbols overlap. I wasn't able to find the flaw in the approach. I could manually tweak `s1` to

```
s1 = xpix[1]-xpix[0] - 13.
```

to give better results, but I couldn't determine a logic behind the `13.`.

Hence, a second approach based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9081553/python-scatter-plot-size-and-style-of-the-marker). Here, individual squares are drawn on the plot and sized accordingly. In a way it's a *manual* scatter plot (a loop is used to construct the figure), so depending on the data-set it could take a while.

This approach uses `patches`instead of `scatter`, so be sure to include

```
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
```

Again, with the same data-points:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 3]
y = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2]
z = ['b', 'g', 'r', 'c', 'm', 'y', 'k'] # in your case, this is data
dx = [x[1]-x[0]]*len(x)   # assuming equally spaced data-points

# you can use the colormap like this in your case:
# cmap = plt.cm.hot 

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, aspect='equal')
ax.axis([min(x)-1., max(x)+1., min(y)-1., max(y)+1.])

for x, y, c, h in zip(x, y, z, dx):
    ax.add_artist(Rectangle(xy=(x-h/2., y-h/2.), 
                  color=c,             # or, in your case: color=cmap(c)                  
                  width=h, height=h))  # Gives a square of area h*h

fig.savefig('test.png')
```

One comment on the `Rectangle`: The coordinates are the lower left corner, hence `x-h/2.`
This approach gives connected rectangles. If I looked closely at the output here, they still seemed to overlap by one pixel - again, I'm not sure this can be helped.

Comment: I just found [this website](http://www.physics.ucdavis.edu/~dwittman/Matplotlib-examples/). Under *More Spatial Binning* another option is outlined, which may be an alternative, @elyase