# Scatterplot Marker Size proportional to axis value - why is the number of pixels for the x and y axis different for aspect='equal'?

Tags: python, matplotlib, size, scatter-plot, markers

My question is as far as I see closely related to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16896244/matplotlib-scatter-plot-symbol-size-based-on-pixel-distance).

I need to plot some data with marker size strictly proportional to the value of the axes. (Already asked the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36458458/python-scatter-plot-area-size-proportional-axis-length)).

My approach is the following:

- Create empty scatterplot for pixel reference
- Scatter 2 points on the lower left and upper right corner
- Limit the axes to exactly these two points
- use `transData.transform` to get the pixel values of those two points
- get the pixel distance as the difference in pixel number of these two points
- (now that I have the distance-to-pixel-ratio, scatter my data with
  `s=(size*dist_to_pix_ratio)**2`; but that is not important right now.)

**Problem is: when I do exactly what I've described, I get two different values for the pixel number for the y-axis and the x-axis.**

Here is a minimal code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(7,7))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111, aspect='equal')

#setting up an empty scatterplot for pixel reference
xedges=[0.0, 1.0]
yedges=[0.0, 1.0]
emptyscatter=ax1.scatter(xedges, yedges, s=0.0)

#set axes limits
ax1.set_xlim(0.00,1.00)
ax1.set_ylim(0.00,1.00)   


# Calculating the ratio of pixel-to-unit
upright = ax1.transData.transform((1.0,1.0))
lowleft = ax1.transData.transform((0.0,0.0))
x_to_pix_ratio = upright[0] - lowleft[0]
y_to_pix_ratio = upright[1] - lowleft[1]

print x_to_pix_ratio, y_to_pix_ratio
```

which returns:

```
434.0 448.0
```

**Can anybody explain why they are not equal?**

I'm not sure if it's relevant, but I'm using Python 2.7.12 and matplotlib 1.5.1

Comment: Additional information:
I have found that the values `x_to_pix_ratio` and `y_to_pix_ratio` as well as their ratio depend on the `figsize` parameter. (Obviously one would expect the actual numbers to vary with figsize, but the ratio?)

Comment: Do a `fig.canvas.draw()` before you calculate the ratio of pixel-to-unit and you should get 434 pixels for each axis.

Comment: @tacaswell could explain it better than me, but some stuffs are only calculated when the figure is being drawn. So sometimes, it is necessary to call a `fig.canvas.draw()` before doing some pixel related calculations in matplotlib.

Comment: @Mladen, It works fine for me in Python `3.5.2` and matplotlib `1.5.3`. So, the code you've written is correct.

Comment: @Jean-Sébastien That worked perfectly, thanks!