# Plotting a circle-matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, geometry

I am trying to plot a circle on a grid. The code that I have written is as follows:

```
import pyplot as plt
from pyplot import Figure, subplot

fig=plt.figure(1)
plt.axis([0,400,0,400])
ax=fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
circ=plt.Circle((200,200), radius=10, color='g', fill=False)
ax.add_patch(circ)
plt.show()
```

Now, I want the center of the circle to be the center of the graph, that is, **(200,200)** in this example. In case of other cases I want it to automatically choose the centre depending on the size that us set. Can this be in some way?

To make it clearer I want to get the x-axis and the y-axis range so as to find the mid point of the grid. How do I proceed?

Answer (score 4):

Your x-axis and y-axis ranges are in your code right here:

```
plt.axis([0,400,0,400])
```

So all you would need is leverage on this a bit like so:

```
x_min = 0
x_max = 400
y_min = 0
y_max = 400

circle_x = (x_max-x_min)/2.
circle_y = (y_max-y_min)/2.

circ=plt.Circle((circle_x,circle_y), radius=10, color='g', fill=False)
```

If you want to catch `x_min` etc. from the command prompt then read out `sys.argv`.

Answer (score 0):

What you want may be `ax.transAxes`, here's the [tutorial](http://matplotlib.org/users/transforms_tutorial.html) for  coordinates transformation.

`ax.transAxes` means the coordinate system of the Axes; (0,0) is bottom left of the axes, and (1,1) is top right of the axes.

```
fig=plt.figure(1)
plt.axis([0,400,0,400])
ax=fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
circ=plt.Circle((0.5,0.5), radius=0.2, color='g', fill=False,transform=ax.transAxes)
ax.add_patch(circ)
plt.show()
```

Note that the radius is also transformed into Axes coordinate. If you specify a radius larger than sqrt(2)/2 (about 0.7) you will see nothing in the plot.

If you want to plot a set of circles, it would be much simpler if you use the function `circles` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24567352/2144720). For this problem,

```
fig=plt.figure(1)
plt.axis([0,400,0,400])
ax=fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
circles(0.5, 0.5, 0.2, c='g', ax=ax, facecolor='none', transform=ax.transAxes)
plt.show()
```

A bit more, if you want see a real circle (instead of an ellipse) in your figure, you should use

```
ax=fig.add_subplot(1,1,1, aspect='equal')
```

or something like that.