# object of type 'ListedColormap' has no len()

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to modify the code from this post

[Python scatter plot. Size and style of the marker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9081553/python-scatter-plot-size-and-style-of-the-marker)

To give a different colour map. I have tried

```
import circlesDrawer as cdraw
import matplotlib as mpl
from pylab import *
figure(figsize=(6,4))
ax = subplot(aspect='equal')
cmap = mpl.colors.ListedColormap(['royalblue', 'cyan',
                                  'yellow', 'orange'])
#plot a set of circle
a = [1,2,3]
x = [1,3,4]
y = [1,3,2]

out=cdraw.circles(x,y,1,c=a,alpha=0.5,fc=cmap)
colorbar()

show()
```

but get the error

```
object of type 'ListedColormap' has no len()
```

> I have no idea how to go about fixing this.

Comment: what is "circlesDrawer"?

Comment: cdraw contains the circles function only. This function is in the post linked. Should I include that also in the post?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You used the wrong argument to supply your colormap. I guess it should be

```
circles(x, y, 1, c=a, alpha=0.5, cmap=cmap)
```

supposing, everthing else is set up correctly.